# Microsoft Azure - programmatic access via keys and creating a new user with minimal permissions

Tags: azure, entra-id

I've just started using Azure, and I'm trying to see how I can achieve the following.

1. Use CLI commands with an access key & ID like in AWS.
2. Create a new user with minimal permissions. Whenever I create a new user with default settings, they can still do things such as list all the users. I want to remove all privileges like this, then add them on manually.

Apologies for asking such a basic question, but I was having trouble finding information online.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use either [Azure PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure) or [Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) to manage Azure.
2. Azure permissions are based on [Role-Based Access Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview); but I don't think it's possible to remove the most basic permissions which all internal users have by default. The [Directory Readers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#directory-readers) role must be explicitly granted to guest users or service principals in order to allow them to enumarate the contents of Azure AD, but this is allowed by default for all internal users.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm using the Azure CLI but you need to login with a username/password. Do you know if it's possible to use an access key/ID instead? Also if I have an Azure VM, how do I get it to use CLI commands without logging in, using RBAC?

Comment: You can create a Service Principal and grant it the required permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096342/what-is-azure-service-principal/48105935; this can be used by Azure applications and/or to log in using management tools such as PowerShell or Azure CLI.

Comment: As for accessing virtual machines, you need to log in; this is controlled by the guest OS, not by Azure. The exact protocols available depende on the OS itself (RDP, PowerShell Remoting, SSH...). Please note that the commands you can send *to Azure* and the commands you can send *to the VM* are not the same things at all.